# Unity won't install

Tags: macos, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I've been trying to install unity onto an external HD for about 3 days now and nothing I find online works. It always fails at the install for all versions. I get the messages:

"The package /Users/username/Downloads/UnityPackages/Unity.pkg failed to install with the following error:

installer: The install failed. (The Installer encountered an error that caused the installation to fail. Contact the software manufacturer for assistance. Authorization is required to install the packages.)

Additional information should be available in the /var/log/install.log file."

Does anyone know how to fix this?
(i have a mac running catalina 10.15.1 if that helps)

Comment: Have you tried to allow `Unity Hub` in the Security Preference, as mentioned on How to [Allow accessibility apps to access your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/mac-help/mh43185/mac)? Might be this can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the unity forum for similar issue that occurred, in mac terminal run command

```
pkgutil --expand /Volumes/Unity\ Installer/Unity.pkg /tmp/Unity.pkg
```

and after command completed, run second command

```
pkgutil --flatten /tmp/Unity.pkg ~/Desktop/Unity.pkg
```

please change the command's above path according to your computer path.
for more information check https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-4-2-installer-failing-on-osx-10-7-4.191914/.